# Regex for length and variety of characters

Tags: regex

I would like to know if the following constraint can be checked with regex:
"Must be at least 5 characters, of which 4 should be letters"

I know how to put the `Must be at least 5 characters` constraint, but not sure of `of which 4 should be letters` if it's even possible with regex.

Comment: What would the other characters be, anything? or numbers or what are you trying to match?

Comment: If you don't have a starting point then things can be a bit difficult. You could find the first letter and then use a lookbehind and lookahead and check if the total is 5 characters maybe? i don't know if i'd use regex for this problem but it's an interesting question.

Comment: I'd use [`/^(?=.{5})(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){4}/i`](https://regex101.com/r/LE0qhg/1) (similar some answers already)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Please use the following regex.

```
(?=.{5,})\w*[a-z]\w*[a-z]\w*[a-z]\w*[a-z]\w*
```

##### Explanation

- `(?=` Lookahead assertion - assert that the following regex matches

  - `.` Any character
  - `{5,}` Not less than 5 repetitions
- `)` Close lookahead
- `\w*[a-z]\w*[a-z]\w*[a-z]\w*[a-z]\w*` Static letters from **a** to **z** in any order

NOTE: The `(?=.{5,})` asserts that the string match 5 or more characters

Answer (score 1):

You can even do this without lookahead! Consider the following RegEx:

`(.+[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*)|(.*[a-z].+[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*)|(.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].+[a-z].*)|(.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].+[a-z].*)|(.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].+)`

Depending on your engine you may have to anchor this using `^` and `$`.

Generation: Simply shifted the `+` quantifier all the way through: The four letters are a must, but the fifth letter can be at any position.

If possible, you should avoid using RegEx for this though, or combine a RegEx that checks whether four letters are present (`.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*`) with a simple length check.

If you need exactly 5 characters to be letters, replace `.` with `[^a-z]`.

If you can use regular grammars, this can be written way shorter:

> S → `%a`A | `.`S'
> S' → `%a`A' | `.`S'
> A → `%a`B | `.`A'
> A' →`%a`B' | `.`A'
> B → `%a`C | `.`B'
> B' → `%a`C | `.`B'
> C → `%a`D | `.`C'
> C' → `%a`D' | `.`C'
> D →  `.`D'
> D' → `ε`

where `S` is the start symbol, `.` stands for any character and `%a` for any letter. Five states are needed to keep track of how many characters have been read; each state X also needs a state X' to keep track of whether a non-letter character has been read yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this pattern:

```
(?i)(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*).{5,}
```

Here, the positive lookahead `(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*)` asserts that there must be four letters (case does not play a role given `(?i)`) either directly or indirectly following each other. Once that condition is met the regex matches any string that is at least 5 characters long

Answer (score 1):

What language or tool are you using?

This sounds like one of those things that doesn't need to be a single regex.

Here's "at least four letters"

```
[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]
```

and here's "at least five characters"

```
.{5,}
```

or even, if you're in a language like PHP, avoid regexes entirely and be more explicitly clear:

```
length($str) >= 5
```